# Selenium Can't Get All Element on Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a script using Python selenium for scraping instagram user post. if user have a 62 post, I want get all of 62 post.

I tried to scroll down until all post loaded and get element/post using xpath and its works. but only 29 element/post, not all of 62 element/post.

```
    driver.get("https://instagram.com/celmirashop/")

    #scroll until all post loaded
    scroll()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.eLAPa")))

    time.sleep(30)

    #getting list cards of posts
    list_cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w']")
    print(len(list_cards))
```

if user have 62 post, I want get element of 62 (all) post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when scrolling instagram, will show new 12 image, but the instagram will remove 12 passed images. I found the solution by saving 12 image when scrolling (every sroll down). so before instagram remove the passed 12 image, I have saved that images on variabel

```
driver.get("https://instagram.com/celmirashop/")


semua_url_lengkap = []
semua_url_post = []
nomor=1
for i in range(50):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    print(nomor)
    nomor+=1
    #mendapatkan list tiap cards update status
    article = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("article")
    list_cards = article.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

    for item in list_cards:

        url_lengkap=item.get_attribute("href")
        semua_url_lengkap.append(url_lengkap)

        segmen = url_lengkap.rsplit('/', 2)
        semua_url_post.append(segmen[1])


print(len(semua_url_post))
print(semua_url_post)
```

Answer (score 0):

They design the application in such a way it's hard to scrape. The elements are lazy loaded so as you scroll, some elements might disappear too.

I'd say use an xpath generic and unchanging like `//a//img` because they will change the class names to something random again.

Also since you already have a method to scroll, start at the beginning. Log all elements and scroll some more and log again and scrape some more. Put on a loop till you find the end of the page element like `//footer`.